# Is there any possibility to reduce the if clauses in R programming?

Tags: r

The code which I have with me looks like, I would like to write these clauses more efficiently in R?
can someone pls help me out

```
if(!is.na(check_param)){
      if(tolower(gender)=="female" & (check_param)){
        if("param1" %in% names(named_vector1)){
          urine_params[["param1"]][["score"]] <- 4
          urine_params[["param1"]][["color"]] <- "6CCC2E"
        }
        if("param2"%in% names(named_vector1)){
          urine_params[["param2"]][["score"]] <- 4
          urine_params[["param2"]][["color"]] <- "6CCC2E"
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: A reproducible example along with expected output would have really helped to understand what you are trying to do and provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't reducing it much (but maybe more readable?), but using `isTRUE(...)`, combining the first two `if statements` and using a `for-loop` over `paramX` lets you remove 2 visible `if` statements. In practice this is only visual however, and it is not truly removing any if-statements.

```
if(isTRUE(check_param) && tolower(gender) == 'female'){
  for(i in paste0('param', 1:2)){
    if(any(i == names(named_vector1)){
      urine_params[[i]][['score']] <- 4
      urine_params[[i]][['color']] <- '6CCC2E'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts that gave me an idea of doing it